# SparseVector to DenseVector conversion in Pyspark

Tags: python, numpy, apache-spark, pyspark

Unexpected errors when converting a SparseVector to a DenseVector in PySpark 1.4.1:

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import SparseVector, DenseVector

DenseVector(SparseVector(5, {4: 1.}))
```

This runs properly on Ubuntu, running pyspark, returning:

> DenseVector([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0])

This results into an error on RedHat, running pyspark, returning:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/mllib/linalg.py", line
>   206, in **init**
>       ar = np.array(ar, dtype=np.float64)   File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/mllib/linalg.py", line 673, in
>   **getitem**
>       raise ValueError("Index %d out of bounds." % index) ValueError: Index 5 out of bounds.

---

Also, on both platform, evaluating the following also results into an error:

```
DenseVector(SparseVector(5, {0: 1.}))
```

I would expect:

> DenseVector([1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])

but get:

- Ubuntu:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/home/skander/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/mllib/linalg.py",
>   line 206, in **init**
>       ar = np.array(ar, dtype=np.float64)   File "/home/skander/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/mllib/linalg.py",
>   line 676, in **getitem**
>       row_ind = inds[insert_index] IndexError: index out of bounds

Note: this error message is different from the previous one, although the error occurs in the same function (code at https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/mllib/linalg.html)

- RedHat: the same command results into a Segmentation Fault, which crashes Spark.

Answer (score 8):

**Spark 2.0.2+**

You should be able to iterate `SparseVectors`. See: [SPARK-17587](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17587).

**Spark < 2.0.2**

<s>Well, the first case is quite interesting but overall behavior doesn't look like a bug at all.</s> If you take a look at the `DenseVector` constructor it considers only two cases.

1. `ar` is a [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytes) object (*immutable sequence of integers in the range 0 <= x < 256*)
2. Otherwise we simply call `np.array(ar, dtype=np.float64)`

`SparseVector` is clearly not a `bytes` object so when pass it to the constructor it is used a an `object` parameter for `np.array` call. If you check [`numpy.array` docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) you learn that `object` should be

> An array, any object exposing the [array interface](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.interface.html), an object whose `__array__` method returns an array, or any (nested) sequence.

You can check that `SparseVector` doesn't meet above criteria. It is not a Python [sequence type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) and:

```py
>>> sv = SparseVector(5, {4: 1.})
>>> isinstance(sv, np.ndarray)
False
>>> hasattr(sv, "__array_interface__")
False
>>> hasattr(sv, "__array__")
False
>>> hasattr(sv, "__iter__")
False
```

If you want to convert `SparseVector` to `DenseVector` you should probably use `toArray` method:

```py
DenseVector(sv.toArray())
```

**Edit**:

I think this behavior explains why `DenseVector(SparseVector(...))` may work in some cases:

```py
>>> [x for x in SparseVector(5, {0: 1.})]
[1.0]
>>> [x for x in SparseVector(5, {4: 1.})]
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ValueError: Index 5 out of bounds.
```

Comment: Good answer. For the first problem, I wondered if he had the same spark versions and python versions on both machines.

Comment: Thanks @Paul. I've posted an edit which should partially explain what is going on here.